# Create one report from two separate collections

Tags: powershell

I am missing something fundamental in PowerShell.

I have a script that generates two collections, computer names with version details of a specific application and a separate user name list that is taken from the computer names list because the user names are in the computer names, for example a computer name is:

```
XXXXXX02jbloggs
```

The owner of this computer is jbloggs and jbloggs is a valid AD object which has a full name of joe blogs.

The ultimate objective of the script is to produce a report with computer names, owner SamAccountName, full name and application details, which the script will specifically check for.

For example,

> what version(s) of Adobe Reader exist on this range of machines

So far I have:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Server BlahBlah.com -Filter {name -like "XXXXXX02*"} | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

$Users = $Computers -Replace '\D*\d*(\w*)', '$1'

$Results = foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $Computer -ClassName Win32_Product | 
    Where-Object{$_.Name -like "*Adobe Reader*"} | 
    Select-Object PSComputerName, Name, Version, InstallDate 
}

$FullNames = ForEach ($user in $Users) {
    Get-ADUser -Server BlahBlah.com -Identity $User -Properties * | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
}
```

- `$Results` gets me a list of computer names, Adobe Reader xxx, the version and install date.
- `$FullNames` gets me a list of the full names based on their user IDs

I do not know how to construct the script so it produces Full Name, User Name, Computer Name, Application Name and Install Date.

This is why I say I am missing something fundamental in PowerShell, I have been looking at custom objects, nested loops and other ideas but to no avail. Really looking for some advice on this type of problem as I several similar examples I need to accomplish.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Get the single current user inside the `foreach($computer in $Computers)` instead of creating two separate foreach.
- Add a calculated property to the select to include `FullName` in
  $Result

---

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Server BlahBlah.com -Filter {name -like "XXXXXX02*"} | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

$Results = foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    $User = $Computer -Replace '\D*\d*(\w*)', '$1'
    $FullName = (Get-ADUser -Server BlahBlah.com -Identity $User -Properties *).Name

    Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $Computer -ClassName Win32_Product | 
    Where-Object{$_.Name -like "*Adobe Reader*"} | 
    Select-Object PSComputerName, Name, Version, InstallDate,@{n='FullName';e=@{$FullName}}
}
```